# Static Private Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am new to Javascript (i.e. learning Javascript CORRECTLY). I'm reading the section on "Static Private Variables" in the Professional Javascript for Web Developers 3rd Edition in Chapter 7.

I was presented with this code, but I feel it is not ideal:

```
(function(){

    //private variables and functions
    var privateVariable = 10;

    function privateFunction(){
        return false;
    }

    //constructor
    MyObject = function(){
    };

    //public and privileged methods
    MyObject.prototype.publicMethod = function(){
        privateVariable++;
        return privateFunction();
    };
})();
```

In this case, they are relying on creating MyObject as a global variable by omitting "var". However, under strict mode, you cannot omit the var keyword and this code would cause an error.

Would my rewrite be correct?

```
var MyObject = (function(){

    //private variables and functions
    var privateVariable = 10;

    function privateFunction(){
        return false;
    }

    var MyObject = function (){
    }

    //public and privileged methods
    MyObject.prototype.publicMethod = function(){
        privateVariable++;
        return privateFunction();
    };

    return MyObject;
})();
```

I'm confused about why the book would omit a solution to this issue and approach with a lazy methodology. I'm a strong believer in using "strict mode" for all my code.

Comment: This question probably belongs over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com - but I would consider your rewrite objectively more correct than the example from the book.

Comment: Your version is fine. That book is fairly old; 4 years is a huge span of time in the Web technology world.

Comment: Sorry! Was my first post on stackoverflow. If someone could move it to a more appropriately location that would be great!

Comment: This book seems so outdated and keeps talking about different patterns that I don't even see people use anymore. I'm reading it, but I don't know what patterns to ignore and what is still used today. It is extremely weird that the author didn't point out that solution but only pointed out the fact that he was doing it to create a global variable.

Comment: A more acceptable way of explicitly creating a global would have been for the example to have assigned to `window.MyObject`.

Comment: @Pointy …though that's still not a declaration, and requires a global `window` object. The OP's rewrite is objectively better.

Comment: @Bergi yes, that's true; honestly I think the OP's solution is the best, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your rewrite is correct. I would advice you to change the book however. This is a really good series:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

This book provides very nice examples and usage + explanations:
https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/